# Want to copy Data from one AWS Account to different AWS Account (file size more than 5 GB)

Tags: amazon-web-services

i want to automated the process of copying the S3 file from one aws account to other AWS Account and file size is more than 5 GB

we are already using the lambda and python function but it support less then 5 GB. Please let us know how we can automate this one.

Answer (score 1):

For copying objects more than 5GB, you must use multipart API. Refer the following link for further more information and how to do that:- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/CopyingObjectsUsingAPIs.html